# Display single custom post

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

i have custom post type events. i want to display content from single post and using  single-events.php .
The code in single-events.php is

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'events',
                   );

              $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  if($loop->have_posts()):while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  ?>

<?php the_content( ); ?>

<?php endwhile;endif; ?>    

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But its displaying the content from all of the posts of custom type- 'events': how do i display the post from just single post

Answer (score 1):

The events post object should already be in `$wp_query` - you don't need to reinitialise it.  Just process it with the standard WordPress loop.  Something like (untested):

```
<?php get_header();

if(have_posts()):while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    the_content( );
endwhile;endif;

get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: this take me to the blank page

Answer (score 0):

**List and single event for same file call.
see the step:**

you can change structure for single event so [go hear](http://tri.be/support/forums/topic/code-for-single-event-view/)

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Event page
 */
get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
                    <div class="page_content">
                            <div class="content_wrapper">
                                    <?php
                                        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                                                get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
                                        endwhile;
                                    ?>

                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- #main-content -->
<?php
get_footer();
```

[image]

```
if(get_post_type()=='tribe_events' && is_single() ) { 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;

} else { 

    //for list code
}
```